# Remove listener on click in tauri_hotkey

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Add a keyboard key listener and when that key is pressed I want to remove that listener, i  use this [crates](https://crates.io/crates/tauri-hotkey)

Adding listener works fine

```
use tauri_hotkey;

fn main() {
    let mut hotkey = tauri_hotkey::HotkeyManager::new();
    let key = tauri_hotkey::Hotkey {
        keys: vec![tauri_hotkey::Key::A],
        modifiers: vec![],
    };
    hotkey
        .register(key, || {
            println!("You pressed A",);
        })
        .unwrap();

    loop {} // infinate loop for prevent main from existing
}
```

Remove the listener when clicking the key

```
    hotkey
        .register(key, || { 
            hotkey.unregister(&key).unwrap();
        })
        .unwrap();
```

it gave a compile error says

```
cannot borrow `hotkey` as mutable more than once at a time
    
second mutable borrow occurs hererustc(E0499)
main.rs(29, 5): second mutable borrow occurs here
main.rs(30, 24): first mutable borrow occurs here
main.rs(32, 14): first borrow occurs due to use of `hotkey`
```

Is there any way to fix this, access hotkey inside the closure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register signature won't allow yourself to change "hotkey" even. First by "&mut self" constraint and second by the callback that's should be 'static

```
  pub fn register<F>(&mut self, hotkey: Hotkey, callback: F) -> Result<()>
  where
    F: 'static + FnMut() + Send
```

An approach could be something like this

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use tauri_hotkey;

fn main() {
    let mut hotkey = tauri_hotkey::HotkeyManager::new();

    let key = tauri_hotkey::Hotkey {
        keys: vec![tauri_hotkey::Key::A],
        modifiers: vec![],
    };

    let is_pressed = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));
    let is_p = Arc::clone(&is_pressed);
    hotkey
        .register(key.clone(), move || {
            let mut is_p = is_p.lock().unwrap();
            *is_p = true;
        })
        .unwrap();

    loop {
        let pressed = Arc::clone(&is_pressed);
        let mut pressed = pressed.lock().unwrap();

        if *pressed {
            hotkey.unregister(&key).unwrap();
            *pressed = false;
        }
    } // infinate loop for prevent main from existing
}
```